# Ubuntu 16.04 swap space fills up, never releases

Tags: ubuntu, memory, swap

Over the course of about a week or so, our Ubuntu 16.04 server's swap space fills up and never releases it, causing other cascading problems on the server.  Namely, an instance of Tomcat running Solr will periodically fail.

The server is a four core VM, with `16g` RAM, and `16g` swap.  Currently has a `swappiness` value of `60`.

We run this server fairly hard, with a large amount of internal HTTP calls to local servers for image processing, etc., much of that through Apache.  As we have been encountering this problem of swap space slowly filling up and never releasing, we have streamlined other areas, but to no apparent effect.  A reboot fixes things, until it fills back up.

I could attach graphs numbers of the swap declining, but not sure how helpful that would be (been tracking with nmon).  For example, after a reboot yesterday our `free -m` output is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16047        4888        7621          32        3536       10729
Swap:         16380           0       16380
```

As can be seen, `0` used for swap.  But once the system dips into it -- for reasons still yet to be determined -- it never really recovers and you get a decline like this:

[image]

And jump forward a few days until it bottoms out around 1:30pm:

[image]

Any suggestions?  or advice on how to continue investigating?

**Update Question**

Based on some feedback in comments, updating question a bit.

Doesn't appear to be heap size for Tomcat, our current JVM settings for Tomcat are `JAVA_OPTS=' -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m'`, which we've bumped up considerably (usually run around 2g). Tomcat's `catalina.out` is telling us `Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2863661056 bytes for committing reserved memory.`

Comment: If the swap gradually fills up, but it's being read (i.e. it doesn't cause a serious slowdown of the system), then it's not a problem as such, but likely just a symptom something leaking memory. Check what `ps` says about the memory usage of various services, and consider if you can restart just those from time to time. (Or, preferably, fix the leaks.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  And definitely realize there are a LOT of factors in tracking down memory leaks.  The physical (virtual) RAM seems fine even when the swap is full, but it's only when swap is full that problems arise.  But point taken, need to check `ps -aux` at time of failures

Comment: You can try `top -o VIRT` and see if any process becomes really large.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, never considered sorting on `VIRT`: getting what seem like huge numbers for Tomcat --> `0.25t` then fell slightly to `99.696g`, as I watch up to `.409t`.  Been using Tomcat for a long time, but never paid much attention to `VIRT`, are these in the realm of normal?

Comment: I guess tomcat is vastly overcommitting memory, so looking at VIRT might not be so useful. Try displaying the SWAP field.

Comment: Good call.  As mentioned in question, swap memory is at `0` currently (and will be until it starts to fall), but will check then.  Thanks.

Comment: did you try using [zram](https://askubuntu.com/q/174579/253474). It's faster than swap anyway, especially in VMs where disk accesses are slow

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a memory leak, possibly in solr, or you have misconfigured your JVM parameters. I guess that, since this is a vm, it is only runnig solr.

You might want to inspect your memory-related JVM parameters.

```
-Xms
-Xmx
```

Note that `-Xmx` specifies the maximum heap size.

You can also configure your JVM to create heap dumps on OOME, you do this by adding `"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/path/filename"` to your JVM arguments. This file will be big and thus you'll probably need diskspace, 32Gb at the very least!

Once you have that, you should see where the leak is happening.

Update: Since this does not appear to be the JVM, we need to look at all processes:

Run this, it will tell you which processes are using most swap:

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r
```

Taken from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-which-process-is-using-swap/

Comment: Our JVM args for running Tomcat: `JAVA_OPTS=' -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m'`, which we've bumped up considerably (usually run around `2g`).  Tomcat's `catalina.out` is telling us `Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2863661056 bytes for committing reserved memory.`, but don't remember any heap size problems.  Will the heap dump still help?

Comment: Nope, please add this information to your question then I will amend my answer.

Comment: That command for looking at processes using swap looks helpful, thanks!  If/when it starts to drop again, can look at that.